# MS Access 2003 - Formatting results in a list box problem

Tags: ms-access, vba, properties, listbox, ms-access-2003

So I have a list box that displays averages in a table like format from a crossyab query. It's just what I need the query is right, there is just one thing. I had to set the field properties in the query as format: standard..decimal:2. Which is exactly what I needed. However..the list box will not pick up on this.

First I typed the crosstab sql into the list box's properties....and then I ran into this problem. So then I actually just created the query object, saved it and set that as the rowsource for the list box. Still won't work....when I open the query it is the correct format.

So is there a way to further format a text box? Is there a way tell it to limit decimal places to one or two on returned values?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the **Format** function in your query to transform your numerical values to formatted strings.  Here is a sample I copied from the Immediate Window:

```
? Format(-.2345,"###,###,##0.##")
-0.23
```

**Edit**: Here is an example using the Format function in a query.

```
SELECT Format(num_field, "###,###,##0.##") AS two_decimals
FROM MyTable;
```

Try a similar approach using your saved crosstab query in place of MyTable.

Comment: ok though I am uncertain about what I should enter into the format field from example?? should i enter everything in paren?

Comment: And if you don't want to clutter your "main complicated query" with formatting, then remember that you can create a new query that simply selects from your main query and in this new query you add the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Your listbox object has a Format property of it's own.  I would suggest entering "#,###.##".  This will display the data with a comma (if needed) and 2 decimal places.

EDIT: Whoops.  I was thinking of a ComboBox control, not a ListBox Control.  By way of apology, please accept a 20% discount off this advice.